# href tag to google maps not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, google-maps, internet-explorer

I have this href tag

```
<a target="blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?q=Κωστή Παλαμά, Αθήνα, Ελλάδα">We are here!</a>
```

which I have tested it in firefox, chrome and its working fine. When I click it , it navigates me to the correct location at google maps.
The problem is that is not working in internet explorer. Do you have any suggestions about how I can make this work in ie too ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: URL encode your query arguments?

Comment: can you please send me the correct url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the parameters of the URL. That is, everything after the `?=`. You can use a number of online URL encoders to do this.

Try `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?q=%CE%9A%CF%89%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%20%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%AC,%20%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1,%20%CE%95%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%B4%CE%B1`.

Comment: Thank you Brett !! It worked! Greetings from Greece!

Answer (score 0):

The link has spaces in between. Remove the space in url.

ex: [https://www.google.com/maps/search/?q=ΚωστήΠαλαμά,Αθήνα,Ελλάδα](https://www.google.com/maps/search/?q=%CE%9A%CF%89%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%AC,%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1,%CE%95%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%B4%CE%B1)
or you can directly hit this in browser and get the complete url.

eg: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kosti+Palama,+Athina+111+41,+Greece/@38.0174024,23.73436,17z/data=!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x14a1a2ec88349261:0xf1e1fcc5be6f1dac!2sKosti+Palama,+Athina+111+41,+Greece!3b1!3m1!1s0x14a1a2ec88349261:0xf1e1fcc5be6f1dac

Hope this helps